# Best design pattern for pipable wrapper when this value matters

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, this, wrapper, pipeline

So... I've been coding up a wrapper (I'm calling it Medium) that seems to be working just fine. Problem is it's pretty ugly:

```
var Medium = function(fn, args){
    var __fn = cloneFunction(fn);
    var __length = fn.length;
    var __args = args.length >= fn.length ? args : fill(fn.length, args);
    var __self = this;

    this.getFn = function(){ return cloneFunction(__fn) }
    this.getLength = function(){ return __length }
    this.getArgs = function(){ return clone(__args) }

    this.pass = function(sprdArgs){ ... }
    this.force = function(sprdArgs){ ... }
    this.call = function(sprdArgs){ ... }
    this.apply = function(thisArg, sprdArgs){ ... }
    this.bind = function(thisArg, sprdArgs){ ... }
    this.rewrite = function(fn){ ... }
    this.recharge = function(sprdArgs){ ... }
    this.clear = function(){ ... }
    this.reload = function(args){ ... }
    this.use = function(funcName, sprdArgs){ ... }
    this.method = function(thisArg, funcName, args){ ... }
}
```

At first I was making it as a simple constructor with some private attributes and getters and the prototype:

```
var Medium = function(fn, args){
    var __fn = cloneFunction(fn);
    var __length = fn.length;
    var __args = args.length >= fn.length ? args : fill(fn.length, args);
    var __self = this;

    this.getFn = function(){ return cloneFunction(__fn) };
    ...
}

Medium.prototype.pass = function(sprdArgs){
    var fnArgs = this.getArgs();
    return arguments.length > 0 
         ? this.use("load", arguments) 
         : this.use("update", fnArgs);
}
...
```

Then I thought it would be cool to add some methods visible to the Medium itself but not to the user. I haven't found a good solution, so I just moved this methods to a getter that returns the called function only if the `this` values matches:

```
var Medium = function(fn, args){
    ...
    this.method = function(thisArg, funcName, args){
        var funcs = {
            load: function(args){ ... },
            update: function(params){ ... },
            execute: function(){ ... }
        };

        return thisArg === __self
            ? funcs[funcName].apply(thisArg, args)
            : null;
    }
}

Medium.prototype.use = function(funcName, sprdArgs){
    var args = clone(arguments);
    var sprdArgs = filter(args, function(elem, i){
        return i !== 0;
    });

    return this.method(this, funcName, sprdArgs);
}
```

Thing is, I also have a `pipe` function and it uses `apply`. Result: I pass the functions to my `pipe`, and the `this` value goes null. Nothing big 99% of the time, but with Medium it simply breaks all the getter's stuff:

```
function pipe(fns){
    var fns = clone(arguments);
    return function(vals){
        var vals = clone(arguments)     
        return reduce(fns, function(args, fn, i){
            var params = i === 0 ? args : [args];
            return fn.apply(null, params);
        }, vals);
    }
}
```

In order to repare it, Medium uses prototype no more. All the functions are declared inside the constructor. Unfortunally, this makes it hard to read - and I think it may cause other problems since in the research I have done about wrappers people usually recomended to implement behaviour on the prototype.

Just in case, I have made a JSFiddle of the whole thing. You can see it here: https://jsfiddle.net/hguerra/0q1urc9o/15/

OBS: You can see some strange functions like `filter`, `reduce` and stuff. Yeah, they are the Array's ones. The build of JS I'm using fails to have any array-related functions so I have made my better to pollyfeel everyone of them. For what I can say, they all work as you should expect for expection of `push` and `unshift`; these two returns the new array instead of the new length. Anyway, these functions are also on fiddle so you can check there if you have any doubts.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do. If you want private methods, you just have to define them inside of your constructor instead of relying on the this. You should probably provide your `pipe`  method if it's the one causing problem with null

Comment: I wll update the post with `pipe`, but it already is on the fiddle, plus it is working good on the rest of the project - in other words, I just don't really thing `pipe` is the problem. (But is sure it could be)
About what I'm aiming to achieve... I look at Medium, and it's ugly. I feel like this is not the best possible solution to the problem, partially because most of the wrappers I see on the net have their methods on prototype. In other words, I only want to know if there's a batter path and if yes, which path is that.

Comment: Just put `._fn`, `._length` and `._args` as properties on your instances and all of your methods on the prototype, that's how everyone is doing it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a little to careless? I feel like giving up the privacy of these variables could make things wreck on my code. Am I reasoning it wrong?